# Installing WWW-development system on Linux

Tags: web-platform-installer

I would like to learn to build WWW-pages on my own computer. I have Linux Mint Helena so is it possible to install some system into it (MySQL, Drupal, ...) so that I can put my pages to it and whose will be shown on the Internet?

---

I have installed php5 but I can't see my PHP-files. What command restarts apache?

---

It works. How can I see my PHP files? I tried to type file:///home/jaakko/Desktop/first.php to Firefox address bar but it says

You have chosen to open first.php which is a: PHP file. What should Firefox do with this file:

- Open with Browse
- Save File

Do this automatically for files like this from now on.

Answer (score 1):

This is a real mess :-D Try to update your initial question instead of "answering" please.

- Follow NARKOZ instructions
- Restart apache with `/etc/init.d/apache(2) restart`
- Always access your website via HTTP protocol (`http://yourhostname`) *not* via file 
  (`file://`)
- You'll find your hostname by typing `hostname` or just use "localhost" for local testing
- If you want to make your website public (which I don't recommend at that stage), use [these instructions](https://serverfault.com/questions/157346/how-necessary-is-a-static-ip-when-running-a-webserver-from-home)

Answer (score 0):

As Linux Mint is a Debian based distribution, you need install your environment with `apt-get install package_name`. Begin with installing Apache, MySQL, PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Comment: Added commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to install the php5 meta package (apt-get install php5) where the libapache2-mod-php5 is included. I'm not sure, but i think it enables the php module automatically. If not just run a2enmod php5 and restart apache.